# SQL count in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm looking to add some form of count function to my table, but am not quite sure how to do it. The table I have is:

| First name | Surname |
| --- | --- |
| Tom | James |
| Mike | James |
| Tom | James |
| Mike | Hamilton |
| William | Morris |
| Mike | James |
| Mike | James |

I would like it to have a count, of the full names that come up twice or more, like so:

| First name | Surname | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tom | James | 1 |
| Mike | James | 1 |
| Tom | James | 2 |
| Mike | Hamilton | 1 |
| William | Morris | 1 |
| Mike | James | 2 |
| Mike | James | 3 |

What is the best way to go about this in SQL? Unfortunately I need the result as per the table above, rather than simply:

| First name | Surname | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tom | James | 2 |
| Mike | James | 3 |
| Mike | Hamilton | 1 |
| William | Morris | 1 |

Comment: Is there an ID column in your table that you're not showing?

Comment: Unfortunately not

Comment: Then your goal is impossible. You must have a column (or columns) that can be used for sorting the rows in the manner you desire. By definition, rows in a table have no defined order despite any pattern you might see (which is an artifact of the execution plan and internal state).

Answer (score 2):

`row_number` function should work

```
select *,
row_number() over(partition by [first name],surname order by [first name]) as count 
from table_name
```

Comment: Closing parenthesis should be before `as count`.

Comment: I believe @Tom is trying to find the count of (first name, and surname) instead of its ranking, please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @YoushaBinArif, the last line says **Unfortunately I need the result as per the table above**

Answer (score 0):

I believe using group by on multiple columns would be a more appropriate approach to

select [first name], surname, COUNT(*) from Employee Group BY [first name], surname;

I believe using group by on multiple columns would be a more appropriate approach to

```
select [first name], surname, COUNT(*) from Employee Group BY [first name], surname;
```

**Result:**

[image]